# I am at a predicament at solving the radius of a circle from a complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

The questions are to show $|z-w|=k$ defines a circle and find the centre and radius. $|z|=x+iy$ and $|w|=a+bi$.

So what I did was substitute the complex numbers in so $|x+iy-a-bi|=k$ eventually getting to $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=k$. Using the general equation for a circle, you can deduce that the center of a circle $(h,k)$ would in this case be $(a,b)$ and that $k=r^2$.

However, I'm confused as to how to state the radius because of the plus-minus signs and stuff. If I were to solve for r, it would be $r=\pm\sqrt{k}$ but I don't know if that's right because the radius is just the distance from the centre so it can't be negative. I'm really stuck on what I think is probably a really easy concept so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: More context might help. If it is $z$ that is intended to vary, then $w$ is the center of the circle and its radius is $k$. But the assumed premises here are not clear from the stated information.

Comment: By **arbitrary** convention, $r$ is **never** negative.  Further, this problem is best attacked with a preliminary **intuition-only** step.  Construe $(z-w)$ to be a complex number $z_1$.  Then, the constraint amounts to $|z_1| = k.$  Note, that **as stated**, the problem is ambiguous, because it is unclear which of $z,w$ is to be construed as a variable and which is to be construed as a **fixed** value.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy "...and $r^2 = k$..." No.  The first paragraph of the query gives $|z-w|=k \implies r = k$, rather than $r = \sqrt{k}.$  The confusion is because the OP's subsequent analysis **mistakenly** concludes that $k = r^2.$

Comment: @user2661923 wait why isn't k = r^2? If you put (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=k equivalent to (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2 wouldn't k=r^2 thus r=√k ?

Comment: The easiest way to see it is to pretend that $w$ is the **fixed value** $(0 + i[0])$ and consider the *resultant* meaning of $|z| = k$ (from the 1st line of your query).  Normally, when $(x + iy) = z = re^{i\theta}$, then $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = |z| = r.$  Consider this against the backdrop of $|z| = k$, when $w = 0.$  Another way of saying the same thing is that $r$ is normally used to represent the distance of $z$ from the origin.

Comment: Still another way of saying the same thing is that when $z$ is represented by $re^{i\theta}$, then the polar equation $r = k$ would represent all complex numbers that are a distance of $k$ from the origin.  That is, all complex numbers that are on the circle of radius $k$, that is centered at the origin.

Comment: As the point Z varies on the complex plane according to $$\left|z-w\right|=k,$$ it traces out a circle centred at the fixed point $W$ and of radius $k\in\mathbb{R}:\;$

if $z=(x+y\,i)$ and $w=(a+b\,i),$ then
$$\left|z-w\right|=k\\ \iff \left|(x-a)+(y-b)i\right|=k\\ \iff \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=k\\ \iff (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=k^2.$$

There are three careless/conceptual mistakes in the OP, all involving moduli of complex numbers; your confusion likely stems from those.